# How to show 3 different templates for posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

i have 3 different templates for posts and i want to show all my posts like
template 1
template 2
template 3
template 1
template 2
template 3
without selecting category in wp admin area.
i know how to do that with categories like if ( in_category(‘2’)){template 1} and etc…

basic php algorithm for array would look like that

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i += 3) {
$arr[$i]; echo ‘template 1 ‘;
$arr[$i + 1]; echo ‘template 2 ‘;
$arr[$i + 2]; echo ‘template 3 ‘;
}
```

but i can’t make it work with wordpress

any help appreciated

so my code is next

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'custom-brand-port', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
  $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;

 endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

thank you in advance

UPDATE

incase someone will have the sam epropblem here is the solution

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'custom-brand-port', 'order' =>  'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;

if( $query->current_post%3 == 0 ) { get_template_part( 'content-1' ); }
elseif( $query->current_post%3 == 1 ) { get_template_part( 'content-2' ); }
elseif( $query->current_post%3 == 2 ) { get_template_part( 'content-3' ); }

endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Could you make a `$counter` variable and increment it within the while loop? Then you'd have something similar to the `$i` in your for loop.

Comment: yeah i tried,but still can't make it work.it shows each post in 3 templates

Comment: Start the counter at 1, and then once it hits 3, set it back to 1. You can check with `if(i % 3 === 0)` . Example: http://codepad.org/xvzB2Fh9